# Automatic recurring payment using YITH subscription and Dokan Stripe

Tags: plugins, customization, woocommerce-offtopic, plugin-recommendation, subscription

I want to enable automatic renewal of recurring payments for subscription product. I have used YITH wooocommerce subscription plugin for subscriptions and Dokan stripe plugin for payment but for first payment it works proper and not works for renewal payment. Can we integrate YITH wooocmmerce subscription plugin with Dokan Stripe as the site is multi vendor?

Comment: I need to use dokan stripe cause we have customized the commission process and also want users able to subscribe products created by multivendors.

Comment: You will need to ask the developers of Dokan Stripe for help. Third party plugins are off topic here (especially if they're extensions for _other_ third party plugins).